# "to apologise to someone for something" or "to apologise to someone about something" or "to apologise to someone over something"

Tags: grammar, prepositions, phrase-meaning, idiomatic-language, british-english

"Downing Street **apologises to** Queen **over** lockdown parties."

The sentence is from the BBC.

As far as I know, the structure should be **"to apologise to someone about something"** or **"to apologise to someone for doing something**."

However, BBC uses it this way and a dictionary (Longman) gives a sample sentence this way:**"We apologize to passengers for the delay."**

It seems that all these 3 prepositions **(over, to, for)** are interchangeable. However, the BBC usage "**apologise to someone over something"** does not seem all that common.

I am confused and want to ask: Can all of these prepositions **(for, about, over)**, and particularly the **"over"** be used with "to apologise" when referring to the issue for which apology is made.?

Comment: **Apologise over** is not very common, but one of the meanings of **over** is 'on the subject of'.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Using **over** is actually quite common when apologising.

For example:

“I want to apologise **over** the way I have behaved”.

“I would like to offer an apology **over** the way I have acted”

**For** and **Over** are commonly used in sentences when apologising, however **about** not so much.

Comment: How about [this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=apologise+for%2C+apologise+over%2C+apologise+about&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Capologise%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Capologise%20over%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Capologise%20about%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Capologise%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Capologise%20over%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Capologise%20about%3B%2Cc0)?

Comment: Yes you are correct @yunus could you please unaccept my answer as it is incorrect